# Problem while installing MUI, and importing MUI components

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

```
home@Avinashs-MacBook-Pro archit-website % npm install @material-ui/core                  
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: archit-website@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/home/.npm/_logs/2022-07-19T00_13_51_943Z-debug-0.log
```

I was trying to install material UI through my terminal, but it doesn't really install showing up some error. I am unsure of how I could solve this error. Kindly Suggest.

Comment: Are you trying to install a specific version of MUI? If you are trying to install v6 then you would use npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Comment: I tried using npm install @mui/material, but it shows the same error

Comment: Your node modules or package.json may be messed up. Try deleting your node_modules folder, package.json and package-lock.json and then installing all your dependencies again.